# regarding the failure of stepwise variable selection in lm

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lm

I built a regression model using all the variables at first.

```
full.model<-lm(y~as.matrix(x))
```

Then I tried to use step-wise variable selection

```
reduce.model<-step(full.model,direction="backward")
```

The running result is shown as follows, looks like it does not do anything. What is the problem of this scenario. I also include the detail of `full.model` in the following.

```
> reduce.model<-step(full.model,direction="backward")
   Start:  AIC=-121.19
   y ~ as.matrix(x)

                 Df   Sum of Sq        RSS     AIC
  <none>                               1.1 -121.19
   - as.matrix(x) 37     21550         21550.7  310.36
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question here? You're trying to dredge through your dataset, but the function stops at the first step? If so, one could perhaps assume you've found an optimum...

Comment: Stepwise regression is generally not a preferred technique. You should check other options before spending lot of time on this.

Comment: Hi, rnso, could you give some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Roman, the step result is what confuses me. Looks like it stops at the original full model. But certainly the full model has too many predictor variables. I am not clear why step is not working here.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `lm(...)` incorrectly. In general, it is always better to build a model formula by referencing columns in a data frame. Try it this way:

```
# example data - you have this already...
set.seed(1)            # for reproducible example
x <- sample(1:500,500) # need this so predictors are not perfectly correlated.
x <- matrix(x,nc=5)    # 100 rows, 5 cols
y <- 1+ 3*x[,1]+2*x[,2]+4*x[,5]+rnorm(100)  # y depends on variables 1, 2, 5 only

# you start here...
df <- data.frame(y,as.matrix(x))
full.model <- lm(y ~ ., df)                 # include all predictors
step(full.model,direction="backward")
# Start:  AIC=3.32
# y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5
# ...
#
# Step:  AIC=1.38
# y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X5
# ...
# 
# Step:  AIC=-0.53
# y ~ X1 + X2 + X5
# 
#        Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
# <none>                  92  -0.53
# - X2    1     53912  54004 635.16
# - X1    1    110870 110961 707.18
# - X5    1    235260 235352 782.37
#
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ X1 + X2 + X5, data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           X1           X2           X5  
#       1.367        2.998        2.006        3.997
```